# Removing a specific element from each array in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, splice

I am trying to remove the 3rd element from each array with the array.

What I have:

```
data =
[["51.9435","-4.26697","450","125"],
["51.9437","-4.26717","450","125"],
["51.9438","-4.26733","450","125"],
["51.944","-4.26748","450","125"]]
```

What I need:

```
data =
[["51.9435","-4.26697","125"],
["51.9437","-4.26717","125"],
["51.9438","-4.26733","125"],
["51.944","-4.26748","125"]]
```

I have assumed using splice but can not think how I would use it with a 2d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on each subarray.

```js
const data = [["51.9435","-4.26697","450","125"],
              ["51.9437","-4.26717","450","125"],
              ["51.9438","-4.26733","450","125"],
              ["51.944","-4.26748","450","125"]]

for( const array of data )
   array.splice(2, 1)
   
console.log(data)
```

Edit: to keep the original data intact, you'd need to copy the arrays prior to splicing.

```js
const data = [["51.9435","-4.26697","450","125"],
              ["51.9437","-4.26717","450","125"],
              ["51.9438","-4.26733","450","125"],
              ["51.944","-4.26748","450","125"]]

const converted = data.map(function(array){
   const copy = array.slice()
   copy.splice(2, 1)
   return copy
})

console.log(data)
console.log(converted)
```

Comment: How would I keep data as it is, and put the result of a splice into a new array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet

```js
data =[["51.9435","-4.26697","450","125"],
       ["51.9437","-4.26717","450","125"],
       ["51.9438","-4.26733","450","125"],
       ["51.944","-4.26748","450","125"]];
data.map( (arr) => {arr.splice(2,1);});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` with `.splice()`.

- `.map()` creates a new array with values returning from callback function.
- `.splice()` removes one or more elements from the array.

**Demo:**

```js
let data =[
  ["51.9435","-4.26697","450","125"],
  ["51.9437","-4.26717","450","125"],
  ["51.9438","-4.26733","450","125"],
  ["51.944","-4.26748","450","125"]
];

let removeIndex = (array, index) => array.map(a => (a.splice(index, 1), a));

console.log(removeIndex(data, 2));
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `splice` supplying the index of the index you want to remove in this case `2` and `1` if you want to remove only one element.

```
data = [
  ["51.9435", "-4.26697", "450", "125"],
  ["51.9437", "-4.26717", "450", "125"],
  ["51.9438", "-4.26733", "450", "125"],
  ["51.944", "-4.26748", "450", "125"],
]

data.forEach( arr => {
// loop over all arrays to get the individual ones. 
  arr.splice(2 , 1) // then call splice. 
})

console.log(data)
```